# grails with spring security can't with create default user in BootStrap

Tags: grails, spring-security, grails-orm, grails-plugin

I'm using Grails with Spring Security plugin and want to create default User when application starts.

I have default `User` and `Authority` classes

My `BootStrap.groovy` is as follows:

```
class BootStrap {

def init = { servletContext ->
    def userAuthority = Authority.findByAuthority('ROLE_USER') ?: new Authority(authority: 'ROLE_USER').save(flush: true)
    def adminAuthority = Authority.findByAuthority('ROLE_ADMIN') ?: new Authority(authority: 'ROLE_ADMIN').save(flush: true)
    def defaultUser = new User(username: "admin", password: "password", accountExpired: false, accountLocked: false,
            passwordExpired: false, enabled: true).save(flush: true)

    assert defaultUser != null

    if (!defaultUser.getAuthorities().contains(userAuthority)) {
        UserAuthority.create defaultUser , userAuthority, true
    }


    if (!defaultUser.getAuthorities().contains(adminAuthority)) {
        UserAuthority.create defaultUser , adminAuthority, true
    }

    assert User.count() == 1
    assert Authority.count() == 2
    assert UserAuthority.count() == 2
}
def destroy = {}
}
```

When I start the application it gives me an exception and fails:

```
Error initializing the application: Cannot invoke method getAuthorities() on null object
```

So it doesn't create a User instance for some reason (have no idea why). 
I'm using default in memory H2 database.

What it can be? I'll really appreciate any help because I've spent a couple of hours on resolving this :(

Comment: you should be getting validation failure. add `println "errors -> $defaultUser.errors"` to check that

Comment: Thank you very much! :-( I've missed that actually User is not default but has additional field that represents one-to-many mapping to other class

Comment: I usually set `grails.gorm.failOnError = true` in the `Config.groovy` in order to catch validation errors in the first place and avoiding `if(!domainInstance.save())` statements

Comment: that is good for one-off cases, like REST-API, where you just need to signalize, that the object couldn't be created for some reason. Although for a normal user interface you need to show, what exactly went wrong with your input. In the latter case `failOnError` is bad

Comment: There some DB which doesn't accepted `user` and `role` as the table names. The Postgres (and possibly H2 too) has this issue, for example. So, better to rename that security domains.